# An object is rotated by mouse in canvas. How to know its rotation degree?

Tags: inkscape, xml, rotate

I rotate an object in canvas by mouse, and would like to know the rotation degree of it. Go to Object → Transform → Rotate doesn't help, because Inkscape views the object is at 0 degree. I go to the XML Editor and find out this value:

```
rotate(-20.518343,117.21587,182.16351)
```

What does this mean? How to convert these numbers to standard degree rotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means an anti-clockwise (negative) rotation of 20.518343°, around the rotation centre: x=117.21587, y=182.16351